# SQL search column where one item in column is substring of another item Update

Tags: sql

This question is a result of my original question, which I think was not quite what I was looking for: [SQL search column where one item in column is substring of another item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628400/sql-search-column-where-one-item-in-column-is-substring-of-another-item)

Is there a way for an sql statement to search if a column string with multiple items contains a certain item that is a substring of another item in the same string, and **also might or might not** include a certain item that the other it item is a substring of. The following is the current sql statement that I am using.

select * from tbltest where platform like '%item%'

platform is the column string that could have multiple items in the string. Item is the specific item that I am searching for in the platform string.

The following is an example of what I am describing and the items that I am searching for. Items to search for in string (These are in a dropdownlist for the user to select). Notice that ASP would be considered a substring of ASP.NET and if the user selects to search for ASP in the column string of items, the records returned would also include the ASP.NET items based on the sql statement that I write above.

ASP
ASP.NET
PHP
HTML
J2EE

So is there a way to add a statement in the where portion of an SQL statement that would do what I am describing above or specifically, based on the example above, search for the ASP items if ASP.NET is also in the string or not?  The following are examples of a few possible platform string combinations.

1)
ASP
ASP.NET
HTML

2)
ASP
PHP

3)
ASP.NET
HTML
J2EE

4)
ASP

5)
ASP.NET

6)
PHP

If I was to search for ASP in the previous platform combinations, it should return records 1, 2, and 4.  If I was to search for ASP.NET, it should return records 1, 3, and 5.  If I was to search for PHP, it should return records 2 and 6.  The format of the platform strings above are exactly as displayed with a line break separating the items if there is more than one item in the string.

Comment: So, what exactly isn't working here? What is your select statement returning (or not returning)?

Comment: When I search for ASP, it will also return all of the ASP.NET records too for the statement in the question.

Comment: What is it using for a line break? \n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to search for your term along with the line break characters to find what you are looking for.

```
select * 
from tbltest 
where platform like '%' + item + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%'
or platform like '%' + item
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives me the error "The expression contains undefined function call CHAR()". Thoughts? @Becuzz

Comment: @SunSunKu Which database are you using?

Comment: @SunSunKu I've got it working on a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cce04/2) here.  Check to see if there is anything different between what you are doing and what I have there.  If you need more help, add another comment here or make a new question.